# Offer questions from closed SE sites to migration review queue of open ones

Tags: feature-request, review, area-51, migration, data-dump

Rather than leave the questions/answers from closed SE sites to be accessed in [data dumps](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128451/data-dump-of-closed-beta-sites?rq=1), could they be filtered and offered to other SE sites based (the most relevant and popular first)?

I offer this for discussion, but one way this could be done is:

First allow mods to sign up for feeds from closed sites, after a proposal in their meta site. Get them to select relevant tags. Then;

1. Filter questions in closed site by tag (remove questions without tags followed by other sites)
2. Sort questions in closed site by no. views (or votes).
3. Select most popular tag of top one
4. Search for that tag on other SE sites that are "following".
5. Add to a migration review queue in the site with most users, if queue>100 then offer to next site (if >1 site following).
6. Get next most viewed (or up-voted) question and repeat until some lower limit (views and/or votes) is reached. Pause if all queues are full (say 100).

I imagine that there are some hidden gems amoungst the closed sites questions that probably warrant more exposure.

Use cases could include the Artificial Intelligence [closed](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6607/artificial-intelligence) and [open](https://ai.stackexchange.com/) versions, [Game Theory](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/47845/game-theory) and [Economics](https://economics.stackexchange.com/), [Theoretical Physics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/23848/theoretical-physics) and [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/).  Perhaps the questions in those closed sites would be a good fit for other sites as well.

Finally, it might allow struggling sites to bow out with pride, knowing that their activity will not be *displayed in the bottom of a locked filing cabinet stuck in a disused lavatory with a sign on the door saying ‘[Beware of the Leopard](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/40705-but-the-plans-were-on-display-on-display-i-eventually).'*

Relevant questions:

[Correct attribution is impossible for failed sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65935/correct-attribution-is-impossible-for-failed-sites/65948#65948)

[Is it allowed to use the content of a (not-closed) SE site to A new Q & A site based on an SE clone?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197033/is-it-allowed-to-use-the-content-of-a-not-closed-se-site-to-a-new-q-a-site-b)

[When do we merge the content of a closed beta site with an existing site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268876/when-do-we-merge-the-content-of-a-closed-beta-site-with-an-existing-site)

Answer (score 3):

The examples of closed sites in your question are all closures from years ago.  The way SE closes sites [has changed since then](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257614/162102), and that makes parts of your proposal not a good fit.

The vast majority of sites that launch and fail today fail in the private beta, within two or three weeks of being launched.  These are sites that never took off.  They do not have hundreds or thousands of good, answered questions looking for a home.  (But I'll come back to cover the ones that do in a minute.)

In principle SE might also close an established beta site for lack of activity and lack of moderation.  This has not actually happened since they changed their approach.  You're proposing a mechanism where sites would plan against a very remote possibility; that's not a good use of development effort and other sites' exploration.

For either type of closure, there's a simpler mechanism (which I have seen applied in some cases, though I don't know if it's current practice): announce the impending closure on the site, ask *that community* what other sites are reasonable migration targets for which categories of questions, and then ask those other sites if they're interested in receiving.  (Or just migrate in the cases where it's clear, but if overlap is that clear the site probably wouldn't have been launched in the first place.)  Instead of building machinery and asking people to do pre-emptive work just in case, deal with cases as they arise, working with the people involved.

By the way, subscribing to specific tags on a young beta is a pretty dicey operation.  Tags and tagging philosophies change a *lot* early on.  That tag your community said it would be interested in might not even exist when the site shuts down.

One final note: one of your suggested paths is from a closed proposal to a newer proposal (not site).  Wholesale migration of questions from a closed proposal to its next incarnation is almost always a bad idea; that first proposal failed for a reason.  But these are only question stubs, not real Q&A.  What usually happens is that interested people cull the list from the closed proposal and bring over the questions they still think are good.